# Using a presolver for MILP problem on pyomo

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming

I have an optimization model written on pyomo. When I run it using gurobi, it outputs the answer to the problem very quickly. Mostly because of its efficient presolver. Is there a way to do a presolve on pyomo before calling the actual solver so I can test my model using non-commercial packages, like couenne or cbc?

Comment: Why not just use those non-commercials like cbc (which also has a presolver) and skip commercials all the way?

Comment: What exactly do you seek to get from the presolve step? Do you want to see if your problem is feasible? Something else?

Comment: AMPL has a built-in presolver ([link](https://ampl.com/REFS/pripre.pdf))

Answer (score 1):

As @gmavrom mentions, it's important to know what you are trying to accomplish with a presolve, as many different techniques may be considered "presolve" operations. The commercial solvers put a lot of engineering effort into the tuning of their respective presolve operations.

As @Erwin points out, commercial AMLs like AMPL also sometimes provide presolve capabilities.

Within Pyomo, you can implement various "presolve" techniques by operating directly on the optimization modeling objects. See the feasibility-based bounds tightening implemented in `pyomo.contrib.fbbt` as an example: https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/pyomo/contrib/fbbt/fbbt.py